# What is the equivalence of LPCTSTR * in C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have an unmanaged C++ function residing inside a Dll that I call from my C# application. Here is the signature of the function:

```
GetCrashMeasurement(LPCTSTR channelName, LPCTSTR properties, LPCTSTR * Values, HANDLE error)
```

where `channelName` and `properties` are input parameter [in]; and `Values` is an output parameter[out].

I'm also using the Platform invoke from my C# application as follows:

```
[DllImport("DrvCrashHAL.dll", EntryPoint = "coCRAL_GetCrashMeasurements")]

public static unsafe extern CoStatus GetCrashMeasurements(string sChannel, string sMeasurements, ref string sValues, IntPtr hError);
```

From my C# application I call the function in the following way:

```
string Text = "";
intptr herror = intptr.zero;
GetCrashMeasurements("channelname","",ref Text,herror);
```

But then my program stops exactly at this line without throwing any exception, and all I see in the output window is the following message:

```
Critical error detected c0000374
Critical error detected c0000374
The program '[4964] ProjectX.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4964] ProjectX.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

My guess is, the problem lies in the marshalling type of `LPCTSTR`.

Could anyone please tell what I`m doing wrong or point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any middle layer of Managed C++ ??

Comment: HI. I'm not sure as i'm  pretty much new to C# and the marshalling stuff..But that's all the code i have..

Comment: So what exactly is written into "Values"? By the variable name, that does not sound like it's a single string. Maybe it's not an out parameter, but an in parameter supposed to be an array?

Comment: what's written in values is a string with the following format (format: <name>=<value> # <name>=<value> # ...).

Comment: Is the C++ dll written by you? can you modify it ?

Comment: "LPCTSTR* Value" sounds more like an array of strings. You sure it is a single string?

Comment: The string Text that has to be returned looks like this :FireCount=0 # TTF=-1.000 # TTF_AS=-1.000 # Duration=-1.000 # TTF_2=-1.0 # TTF_AS_2=-1.0 # Duration_2=-1.0

Comment: The C++ dll is not written by me, nor can i modify it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from what you've provided, parameters 1, 2 and 4 should marshall just fine. The problem is likely to be parameter 3.

Error c0000374 is heap corruption. That would fit.

The issue in trying to solve your problem is to know what that 3rd parameter does. It's declared as a kind of `char**`, and as an [out] parameter I would expect it to be output as a `char*`. In other words, I would expect the function to actually output a pointer, not a string, with the expectation that the caller will receive that pointer and copy a (null-terminated) string from it.

You can investigate calls like this by redefining the entry point as an int* or int** and passing in an intptr. That way you should (a) fix the crash and (b) get to see the output value (as an int or pointer). You may have to do your own marshalling for this one. Given a pointer to a COM BSTR you can easily retrieve the value you need.

However, according to my reading of the Interop spec, this should work correctly with a declaration of `out string sValues` and not `ref`. The heap corruption would be happening when the function is called, not when it returns.

This is helpful, if rather technical: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx.

I suggest you try that first. If not, maybe try the debugging route to see what pointer you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

As @jester noticed `LPCTSTR* Values` sounds more like an array of strings. Can you try to change your third parameter to be an array of strings?

```
public static unsafe extern CoStatus GetCrashMeasurements(string sChannel, string sMeasurements, string[] sValues, IntPtr hError);
```

and call it as follows

```
GetCrashMeasurements("channelname","",new[] { Text },herror);
```

Also you can specify `MarshalAs` on `sValues`.

```
public static unsafe extern CoStatus GetCrashMeasurements(string sChannel,
                                                          string sMeasurements,
                                                          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
                                                          string[] sValues,
                                                          IntPtr hError);
```

Comment: i just tried..but it keeps having the same behavior